# How to sort by custom field in datatable?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a html table to display the user status,it has three status "Pass,In process and Fail", I hope the user can click the Status, it can sort by status about first -> Pass ,second ->Fail,third -> In process. and not order by A to Z. thanks
Here is my html code ,

```
<table border="1"> 
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Status</th>
<tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Pass</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Billy</td>
  <td>In process</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Andy</td>
  <td>Fail</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Tom</td>
  <td>In process</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Pass</td>
</tr>
```

[image][image]

the following is what I hope the final output result is that
[image]

But I find the solution in w3school 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sort_table
and other website, I can't find the solution, so I hope someone can help me,Thanks

Comment: Are you using the datatables jQuery library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the order of the statuses in an array and check the position (index) of them in the array in order to switch or not.
I've changed the w3school code a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sort a HTML Table Alphabetically</title>
<body>
Click on Status cell to Sort
<table border="1" id="myTable"> 
  <th>Name</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable()">Status</th>
<tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Pass</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Billy</td>
  <td>In process</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Andy</td>
  <td>Fail</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Tom</td>
  <td>In process</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Pass</td>
</tr>   
</table>

<script>
function sortTable() {
  var orderStatus = ["pass","fail", "in process"];
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.getElementsByTagName("TR");
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (orderStatus.indexOf(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > orderStatus.indexOf(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch= true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We fetch all the text of the column and save them with the rows in a an array, then sort and replace in the table:

```
function sortTable() {
  var orderStatus = ["Pass","Fail", "In process"];
  var array = []
  $('tr:not(:first)').each((index, child) => {
    array.push({text: $(child).find('td:nth-child(2)').text(), element: child});
  });


  array.sort((a,b) => orderStatus.indexOf(a.text) > orderStatus.indexOf(b.text));

  $('tr:not(:first)').remove();
    array.forEach((a) => {
      $('table').append(a.element);
    });
}
```

example can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/8oru7ahp/2/

Comment: This looks to be alphabetical sorting.. which is not answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v9334apr/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Sort a HTML Table Alphabetically</title>
<body>

<p>Click the button to sort the table alphabetically, by name:</p>
<p><button onclick="sortTable()">Sort</button></p>

<table border="1" id="myTable">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th onclick="sortTable()">Status</th>
<tr>
  <td>Peter</td>
  <td>Pass</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Billy</td>
  <td>In process</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Andy</td>
  <td>Fail</td>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Tom</td>
  <td>In process</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td>Mary</td>
  <td>Pass</td>
</tr>   
</table>

<script>
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, pass, fail, inProgress;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");


  pass = []
  fail = []
  inProgress = []

  rows = table.rows
  /*Loop through all table rows*/
  for (i = 1; i < (rows.length); i++) {
    var x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "pass") {
      pass.push(rows[i])
    }
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "fail") {
      fail.push(rows[i])
    }
    if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "in process") {
      inProgress.push(rows[i])
    }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (pass.length); i++) {
    table.appendChild(pass[i])
    }
        for (i = 0; i < (fail.length); i++) {
    table.appendChild(fail[i])
    }
        for (i = 0; i < (inProgress.length); i++) {
    table.appendChild(inProgress[i])
    }

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```